# I think i have a problem with the parenthesces

Tags: string, haskell, switch-statement, show

Im sorry i have posted codes the entire day, now i have this one and i have no idea why its not working. I have an error that doesnt tells me exactly what my problem is, someone told me to turn on the warnings so it could be easier but i dont know how do to that. If you give this code a monomian, it should give you the monomian as a string. The monomian is a (a,b), so thats why the code is full of fst and snd.

```
showMon :: Monomio -> String
showMon = \m -> case (fst m) == 0 of{ True -> " ";
                                    False -> case (fst m) == 1 of{ True -> case (snd m) == 0 of{ True -> "1";
                                                                                               False -> case (snd m) == 1 of{ True-> "x";
                                                                                                                            False -> "x^" ++ (show (snd m));}}
                                                                   False -> case (fst m) < 0 of{ True -> case (snd m) == 0 of{ True -> show 1;
                                                                                                                     False -> case (snd m) == 1 of { True -> "-x";
                                                                                                                                                     False -> "-x^" ++ show (snd m);}}                                                                                        
                                                                                          False -> case snd m == 0 of{ True -> show 1;
                                                                                                                       False -> case snd m == 1 of{ True-> (show fst m) ++ "x";
                                                                                                                                                    False-> (show fst m) ++ "x^" ++ show (snd m);}}}}}
```

```
Polinomios.hs:146:108: error:
    Unexpected case expression in function application:
        case (snd m) == 0 of
          True -> "1"
          False
            -> case (snd m) == 1 of
                 True -> "x"
                 False -> "x^" ++ (show (snd m))
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?
    |
146 |                                                                     False -> case (fst m) == 1 of{ True -> case (snd m) == 0 of{ True -> "1";     |
```

Comment: Please use a reasonable indentation standard that doesn't require us to horizontally scroll to read your code.

Comment: Also, stop treating `case` expressions like  a more verbose version of `if` expressions. Either *use* `if`, or better yet, replace the `case` expressions with guards to simplify the amount of nesting.

Comment: Yes, i have been told that it doesnt looks good, but i have been teach to do it this way, and i have to do it like this right now, if you guys could help me anyways would be great!.

Comment: If this is for a class with a teacher, then you should ask said teacher for help with their requirements instead of us.

Comment: If this was the style of Haskell your teacher is enforcing, I would seriously question that class. It's very un-Haskell-like to write code in this fashion.

Comment: I would also recommend Learn You A Haskell (have the hard copy myself). In your case, I would recommend chapters 1 through 5. It takes about 2 hours to read all it.

Comment: @DevNebulae Personally, I'm fine with making beginners use `case .. of True -> .. ; False ..` at the very beginning, and move to `if` later on, since that stresses that pattern matching is the real primitive which should be learned, and the rest is only syntactic sugar. I am instead not ok with the absurd indentation style -- I am guessing that might not be a requirement from the teacher.

Comment: @chi Even if you wanted to go that route, wouldn't `case fst m of 0 -> foo; _ -> bar` be way better than `case fst m == 0 of True -> foo; False -> bar`?

Comment: @JosephSible Indeed, that's what I suggested in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the ones who tried to help, the main problem was that i tried to do ;}} instead of }};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code, re-indented for clarity. It is still quite hard to read.

```
showMon :: Monomio -> String
showMon = \m -> case (fst m) == 0 of
  { True -> " ";
    False -> case (fst m) == 1 of
      { True -> case (snd m) == 0 of
          { True -> "1";
            False -> case (snd m) == 1 of
              { True-> "x";
                False -> "x^" ++ (show (snd m));
              }
          } -- **
        False -> case (fst m) < 0 of
          { True -> case (snd m) == 0 of
              { True -> show 1;
                False -> case (snd m) == 1 of
                  { True -> "-x";
                    False -> "-x^" ++ show (snd m);
                  }
              } -- **
            False -> case snd m == 0 of
              { True -> show 1;
                False -> case snd m == 1 of
                  { True-> (show fst m) ++ "x";
                    False-> (show fst m) ++ "x^" ++ show (snd m);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

In the points marked with `-- **` above a semicolon is missing, making the compiler produce a weird error message, since we are essentially trying to apply a `case` expression to some arguments in this way.

Some suggestions to improve this:

You don't have to use `fst,snd`, you can pattern match on the input argument. Instead of `\m -> ...`, you can use `\(m1,m2) -> ...` and then use the two components directly.

You don't have to check `fst m == 0`, `fst m == 1` in that way. You can instead use (trying to mimic your style)

```
case m1 of  -- recall m1 is (fst m)
  { 0 -> .... ;  -- it is 0
    1 -> .... ;  -- it is 1
    _ -> ....    -- it is something else
  }
```

In principle, with guards you can even incorporate checks like your `fst m < 0`.

Comment: Thanks i changed fst m and snd m to m1 and m2 , but still doesnt work, thanks for taking the time to do it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you can reduce this entire function down to a few simple cases.

```
showMon (m, n) | m < 0 = "-" ++ showMon (negate m, n)  -- negative terms
showMon (0, _) = " "  -- empty term
showMon (m, 0) = show m -- terms with x^0
showMon (m, n) = let coeff = if m == 1 then "" else (show m)
                     exp = if n == 1 then "" else ("^" ++ show n)
                 in coeff ++ "x" ++ exp -- other terms, with coefficients and exponents of 1 dropped
```

---

A `case` expression can handle multiple different values. If you *do* need to match against a Boolean value, that's what the `if` expression is for.

```
if x then y else z
```

is equivalent to

```
case x of
  True -> y
  otherwise -> z
```

---